# Ransack search by multiple select(checkbox) on check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

Shows no error in my code, iam using Ransak search ,but iam not getting the search output. i want to get the output when i check size option from the checkbox. if i click medium ,i want display all medium dresses,like all
please give me a solution

this is my checkbox

[image]

here is my code

product/index.html.slim

`= search_form_for @product_search, url: shop_index_path do |f|
  = f.label :size_cont, "Size Available"
  - StandardSize.all.each do |s|
    = check_box_tag('product_search[standard_sizes_id_eq_any_cont][]', s.id ) 
    = s.name`

here my ShopController.rb

`class ShopController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @product_search = Product.ransack(params[:q])
    @products = @product_search.result(distinct:true).page(params[:page]).per(8)
    @product_search.build_sort if @product_search.sorts.empty?
  end`

model standardsize.rb

`class StandardSize < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end`

here my model `product.rb`

`class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :standard_sizes
end`

this is my server getting

`Started GET "/shop?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bname_cont%5D=dress&q%5Bprice_paisas_gteq%5D=&q%5Bprice_paisas_lteq%5D=&product_search%5Bstandard_sizes_id_eq_all%5D%5B%5D=3&commit=Search" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-07-23 10:12:42 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ShopController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"name_cont"=>"dress", "price_paisas_gteq"=>"", "price_paisas_lteq"=>""}, "product_search"=>{"standard_sizes_id_eq_all"=>["3"]}, "commit"=>"Search"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT`users`.* FROM`users`WHERE`users`.`id`= 1  ORDER BY`users`.`id`ASC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you've configured Ransack otherwise, all search parameters should be nested under `@q`. I've also had success with `_in` instead of `_eq_any_cont`.

Replace

```
= search_form_for @product_search, url: shop_index_path do |f|
  = f.label :size_cont, "Size Available"
  - StandardSize.all.each do |s|
    = check_box_tag('product_search[standard_sizes_id_eq_any_cont][]', s.id ) 
    = s.name
```

with

```
= search_form_for @q, url: shop_index_path do |f|
  = f.label :size_cont, "Size Available"
  - StandardSize.all.each do |s|
    = f.check_box :standard_sizes_id_in, {multiple: true}, s.id, nil
    = s.name
```

Comment: same problem again   `Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by ShopController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"name_cont"=>"", "price_paisas_gteq"=>"", "price_paisas_lteq"=>""}, "standard_sizes_id_in"=>["1"], "commit"=>"Search"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECTusers.* FROMusersWHEREusers.id= 1  ORDER BYusers.idASC LIMIT 1
  Order Load (0.3ms)  SELECTorders.* FROMordersWHEREorders.user_id= 1 ANDorders.status= 0 LIMIT 1
  StandardSize Load (0.2ms)  SELECTstandard_sizes.* FROMstandard_sizes``

Comment: `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)` ,shows this error now

Comment: Edited. If that doesn't work post the full stake trace please. http://dpaste.com/

Comment: thank you . thank you thanks a lot dear ... it worked  :) .you really helped me from this trouble :).. thank you again